# Mysql data convert

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do `DATE_SUB( ".$date." , INTERVAL 100 DAY )` if the type of the column where the date is stored is varchar(255) or I need to convert that column to "DATE" type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you store your data in yyyy-mm-dd format.
Otherwise you ought to change it to this one.

Comment: The date is stored in d-m-y format. If I try to query mysql using query 'SELECT * from videos WHERE user_id=$id AND date_uploaded >= DATE_SUB( ".$date." , INTERVAL 100 DAY )' I can't get any result.

To convert date I'm using PHP command '$date = date('d-m-y')'

What can be the problem with this query?

Comment: @Sergio the problem is OBVIOUS: you need to convert date stored in the database. You need to convert that column to "DATE" type, yes. And you will do yourself a HUGE favor by doing that. (Note that first you have to convert this columns's value, or you'll lose the data. )

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date stored as varchar using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)() function in mysql. e.g.

`DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(date_column_name,'%d-%m-%y'),INTERVAL 100 DAY)` , just make sure the date formatting string matches the format of whatever is in you date column.

Comment: +1: Better to explicitly convert, if not actually correct the data type for the column in question.